# Query custom posts type by custom field on archive page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following query in an archive-mypostype.php template to list custom posts with a specific custom field value.

```
$args = array(
   'numberposts'    => -1,
   'post_type'      => 'mypostype',
   'meta_key'       => 'custom_field_name',
   'meta_value'     => true,
   'paged'          => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
```

These posts are assigned to a custom taxonomy. The query works great on the root archive for the custom post type, but viewing each taxonomy archive page displays all posts and not just the posts for the current taxonomy. How do I amend the query so that its possible to only see the posts for the current taxonomy archive?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to the `WP_Query` codex page and its `taxonomy` parameter, [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

With this parameter, you will be able to retrieve posts in a certain taxonomy.

```
$args = array(
   'numberposts'    => -1,
      'post_type'      => 'mypostype',         
      'paged'          => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
      'meta_query'     => array(
           array(
               'key'=> 'custom_field_name',
               'value'=> 'true',
           )
      ),
      'tax_query' => array(
           array(
               'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy', // change this with the cpt taxonomy name
               'field'    => 'slug',
               'terms'    => get_query_var( 'category_name' ), // change it with the query var needed
           ),
       )
);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm after, sorry, if I wasn't clear. I just want to be able to dynamically display the posts for each taxonomy, filtered by the custom field above. If I remove the $wp_query, it works when visiting each taxonomy archive page, but adding this query shows all posts for each taxononomy archive page